# Upload file converted in base64 angular after crop

Tags: php, angularjs, upload, crop

I use https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop to crop an image. With this module the cropping image is converted in base64.
Then cropping I would upload to a server (with PHP). I tryed to make $.post taking $scope.croppedImage value but without succes!
Any idea to make?

Comment: Can you post your code? Error messages?

Comment: there's a limit of byte.... so I've to convert before!

Comment: there's a limit of byte... in firebug post message I see half of base64 and then a message (in italkian in my case) that is a kind of limit size!